# Using Android w/ broken digitizer

Tags: touchscreen, broken-screen, vnc

My Nexus 4 digitizer is broken but I have several things I could use it for that don't need a touchscreen, or a screen at all....if I install Ubuntu Touch.

Here are instructions for installing Ubuntu Touch on Nexus 4 (stable release): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

It appears that a few of the steps (such as "accept the unlock agreement on the device's screen" or "enable debug mode on the device") require using the screen.

Question: is there any way for me to do those without touching the screen? Can I pair a BT keyboard+mouse or enable a VNC server or something else?

Comment: Any way to get a "host" USB input device (like mouse). From old to new it is the one thing I can think of that would have no security, no passwords, not touch needed, they just started moving a curser around when plugged.  Even a wireless, but the kind of wireless that requires a dongle (not bluetooth pairing).

Comment: @Psycogeek so are you saying that if I connect a USB mouse via OTG adapter to a locked Nexus 4, I will immediately see a cursor and can click through to the settings screen to enable debug mode?

Comment: I do not know,  if already locked it might add its own difficulties. that would just be what I would try